# how does Java handle && inside if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I don't understand the reason why the follow java code throws a ArrayIndexOutofBound exception

```
    while (intArray[j] < intArray[j - 1] && j > 0) {
        int temp = intArray[j - 1];
        intArray[j - 1] = intArray[j];
        intArray[j] = temp; 
        j--;
    }
```

It appears that even if I AND(&&) both conditions, it will execute one of the conditions first to check if it qualifies the condition, in this case, it will be intArray[0] < intArray[-1] and cause out of bound exception. Which confuses me at first, now I just wandering, why does the program behave that way?

Comment: why do you use `while` statement? in this case, you may use `for`

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko it's part of my insertion sort practice demo code.
 http://blog.csdn.net/shanwu1985/article/details/46585999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is evaluated from left to right, which means `intArray[j] < intArray[j - 1]` is evaluated first. Therefore if j<=0, you'll get an exception.

Changing the order to

```
while (j > 0 && intArray[j] < intArray[j - 1]) {
```

will prevent the exception (assuming the initial value of j is not too high).

Comment: is it always evaluated from left to right ? or depends on Java Compiler ?

Comment: @shanwu, not only for java, but also for for all language. yes, left to right.

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this:

```
while (j > 0 && intArray[j] < intArray[j - 1]) {
        int temp = intArray[j - 1];
        intArray[j - 1] = intArray[j];
        intArray[j] = temp; 
        j--;
    }
```

If the first condition, `j > 0` is false, then the second one isn't evaluated (and does't throw any exception of course).

If you used single `&` instead of `&&`, the order of conditions wouldn't matter, because both would be evaluated, even if the first one was false.

Edit

A simple example of the difference between `&` (bitwise AND operation) and `&&` (Conditional-AND)

```
public class LogicalOperators {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 0;
        int k = 5;

        if(n != 0 && k % n == 0) {
            System.out.println(n + " is a divisor of " + k);
        }

        if(n != 0 & k % n == 0) {
            System.out.println(n + " is a divisor of " + k); // throws ArithmeticException
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you give me an example on '&' in this case ? I thought '&' is for bit operation...

Answer (score 1):

Java uses lazy evaluation from left to right. You may be getting this exception for three reasons.

- If j<0 then intArray[j] will throw an exception
- If j<1 then intArray[j-1] will throw an exception
- If j>=intArray.length, then intArray[j] will throw an exception.

Also, your loop should consider j < intArray.length

Anyway, if you're trying to implement a sinking/bubble algorithm, your code is wrong, it will stop as soon as it finds a sorted couple of elements. And repeat itself ad nauseam.

Comment: actually, it's insertion sort... the full code is as follow:
http://blog.csdn.net/shanwu1985/article/details/46585999

Comment: Ok. Note that && is different to &. The second one will perform every operation within the conditions, whereas the first one will stop as soon as it finds a false. Same for || and |, the first one will stop as soon as it finds a true condition

Answer (score 0):

This will fail when the value of j will become 1. It will enter into the loop after executing to the last step it will become 0. When again it reaches the next step it will compare int[0] to int[-1] which will eventually throw arrayindexout of bound because it will get evaluated befor j>0.